# what is the best way to write these java arrays?

Tags: java

I am stuck on my class work:

> Create an application containing an array that stores eight integers. The application should
>
> 1. display all the integers, (done)
> 2. display all the integers in reverse order,
> 3. display the sum of the eight integers, (done)
> 4. display all values less than 5,
> 5. display the lowest value, (done)
> 6. display the highest value, (done)
> 7. calculate and display the average, (Done)
> 8. display all values that are higher than the calculated average value.

I must use (or attempt to use) an array; also must use at least one loop to "traverse" (move through) the array. This also due @ 23:59 mountain standard time tonight

What am I doing wrong?

```
package numberlistdemo;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class NumberListDemo 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
             int n[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int lowest = 1000;
    int highest = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int OverF = 0;
    int rev = 0;
    int OverAve= 0;
    
        for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
           
        {
            
            int cur = n[i];
            if (cur < lowest) lowest = cur;
            if (cur > highest) highest = cur;
             sum += cur;
            
        }
         double ave = sum / n.length;
         
         for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
         {
            int cur = n[i];
            if (cur > ave) OverAve = cur;
         }
         
       for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
       {
          
           int LowF = n[i];
           if (LowF < 5) five = LowF;
           if (LowF > 5) OverF  = LowF;
       }
       
        
        
            //3
            System.out.println("Total of the Array is " + sum );
            //1
            System.out.println("The number we are using are " + Arrays.toString(n));
            //4
            System.out.println("All values lower the 5 are " + five );
            ////2
             for (int counter=n.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
        {
           System.out.println("The reverse order of the numbers are " + (n[counter]));
        }         
             //5
            System.out.println("The lowest value is " + lowest);
            //6
            System.out.println("The highest value is "+ highest);
            //7
            System.out.println("The average is " + ave);     
            //8
            System.out.println("All numbers higher than the average are: " + OverAve);
           
  
    }
}
```

I get this

```
Total of the Array is 36
The number we are using are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
All values lower the 5 are 4
The reverse order of the numbers are 8
The reverse order of the numbers are 7
The reverse order of the numbers are 6
The reverse order of the numbers are 5
The reverse order of the numbers are 4
The reverse order of the numbers are 3
The reverse order of the numbers are 2
The reverse order of the numbers are 1
The lowest value is 1
The highest value is 8
The average is 4.0
All numbers higher than the average are: 8
```

Comment: There are several typos and missing brackets in the code. Fix those first.

Comment: OK, so you calculated the sum by looping over the array, and you have the average. You can also, in the single loop, find the lowest and highest values. There are different approaches to reversing an array, but the easiest is create a new array, and loop over the original array in reverse. While you are filling the reversed array, find any value greater than the calculated average and display it. Then just output the results.

Comment: Check your code carefully. Example, in your array, there's an extra ` , ` between the numbers `4` and `5`  `( int [] n= {1,2,3,4,,5,6,7,8};)`

Comment: Also, use an IDE. The issue @Scar noted would have been flagged immediately, and you would have access to a debugger.

Comment: Fixed the (,) problem.

Comment: @MatthewHunt, after your latest effort, you will be (a)printing the results on every iteration of the loop, (b)not calculating the average correctly except on the last interation, and (c)you are doing noting with reversing the array or dealing with greater than the mean. Please see my answer for the first part of the loop to help (which matches what user2664209 was trying to explain about scope).

Comment: right now all i get is 

Tottal of the Array is 1
The number we are using are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
All valuses lower the 5 are true
The reverse order of the numbers are 7.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at numberlistdemo.NumberListDemo.main(NumberListDemo.java:42)
C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: With Changes now it repeats 8 times with sum just counting the numbers

Comment: @KevinO did the fixes that I know how to do. And posted what come out of the run

Comment: @MatthewHunt, I already explained why you would see the output 8 times: You have wrapped everything inside the for loop. It now appears you have `sum = sum + 1`, which merely increments the sum rather than adding the values from the array to it (it must be `sum += n[i]`. Move the closing of the `for` loop above the system.out. Replace the existing `for` loop with something that works (e.g., the sample code I provided).

Comment: Sorry I was asking in to many places. :( I copyed the wrong thing in here.

Comment: @MatthewHunt, you cannot in the initial loop calculate the "average", so you will need to (a)move the declaration outside of the current loop, and (b)calculate it after the loop is complete. Likewise, you cannot find all values greater than the mean. It is difficult to reverse the array in that loop (see earlier answers).

Comment: I have read what you posted and I know what needs to be done, just have no clue how to do this. I have made another change

Comment: You now have sum adding twice; remove the `sum = sum + n[i]` since it is already handled by the `sum += cur` line. After the loop, you can calculate the average (move the `double ave = sum / n.length;` outside the loop). You will need another loop to: (a)reverse the array, (b)find values greater than the average. These two things can be done in the same loop. You have variables with scope limited to the for loop, as others noted earlier.

Comment: if you can I really need some help with this understanding. I am doing this class online and I do not have access to campus. I have Skype and would enjoy learning more

Comment: did the edits going to try to start the next loop

Comment: @MatthewHunt, try a chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108129/java-arrays (if I created the room correctly)

Comment: added what I think is right for the next loop

Comment: @KevinO my rep is low to talk there

Comment: @MatthewHunt, I must sign off. I apologize about the chat (having never tried to use it before). The assignment wants *all* the numbers > 5, and *all* the numbers > the average, so you will need an array to track those. Given that you must also reverse the array, I suggest you create three new arrays. Create three int index variables. Run the for loop backwards (`for int i = n.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)`, put the value of n[i] into the one array (e.g., rev[revIdx++]). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sample loop to obtain sum, lowest, and highest integer from an array

```
int lowest = 1000;
int highest = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  int cur = array[i];
  if (cur < lowest) lowest = cur;
  if (cur > highest) highest = cur;
  sum += cur;
}
```

**Edit**: the latest code updates made some progress, but likely do not quite meet the specified requirements. There are some difficulties in knowing the full requirement (e.g., output format).

1. Output Only

The current example is displaying the output (one entry per line). It is not clear if one only needs to display the output or actually reverse the array. If the only requirement is to output the reversal, the numbers larger than 5 and larger than 8, the the following three loops will work. One is mostly already in the suggested code.

```
System.out.println("The reversed array is: ");
for (int counter < n.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    System.out.print(n[counter] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Note that these two should probably be in a method

```
final int lessThan = 5;
System.out.println("The numbers in the array less than " + lessThan + " are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
  if (n[i] < lessThan) {
    System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
  }
}
System.out.println();

System.out.println("The numbers in the array greater than the mean " + ave + " are: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
  if (n[i] > ave) {
    System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
  }
}
System.out.println();
```

2. Create a new reversed array

It would make more sense for the assignment to require actually reversing the array. In that case, there are a couple of approaches. Probably the easiest is to create a new array and reverse the elements into it. Essentially it is the same loop as above, but placing the elements of `n` into the array rather than outputing them to the screen. (Note: @Debosmit proposed an example that does not require the additional index variable).

```
int[] reversed = new int[n.length];
int idx = 0;
for (i = n.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
   reversed[idx++] = n[i]];
}
```

Later then one can use the same output approach as was used for displaying all of the original entries:

```
System.out.println("The reversed array is: " + Arrays.toString(reversed));
```

Comment: For n.length; i++; is there a differance from i++ to ++i?

Comment: @MatthewHunt, in a for loop, there is no difference between `i++` and `++i`; elsewhere it can matter.

Comment: made these changes and I still have a repet of 1-8 and then a total come out

Comment: @MatthewHunt it is because the closing of your `for` loop is below the print statements. Move the closing brace of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message? 
since you are not using curly braces`{ }`  your local variable `int i` will only exist within these lines:

```
 for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
         sum = sum + n[i];
```

and NOT these:

```
double rev = n.length - i - 1;

boolean l = (n[i] < 5);
```

Comment: Ok Now looks like this.

`public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     int [] n= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
     {
         sum = sum + n[i];
         
         double ave = sum / n.length;
         
         double rev = n.length - i - 1;
         
         boolean l = (n[i] < 5);
         
        }`
and then they outs after that

Comment: You have to understand the concept of local variables. All variables declared within the { } will only exist there. Meaning, after the loop ends, these variables are forgotten. You can declare them on top of the loop if you want to reference them later.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Well... I'll contribute. Here is how to reverse...

```
// note this will change the original array
for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++) {
    int t = n[i];
    n[i] = n[n.length - 1 - i];
    n[n.length - 1 - i] = t;
}

// this will not change the original array
int[] newArr = new int[n.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++) {
    newArr[n.length - 1 - i] = n[i];
}
// you can now return `newArr` or something since it is `n` reversed
```

Now to look at all values that are higher than the calculated average value. I think you already have the sum of the numbers. Lets call it `sum`. `avg = sum/n.length`.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++) {
    if(n[i] > avg)
        System.out.println(n[i]);
}
```

All numbers less than 5.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++) {
    if(n[i] < 5)
        System.out.println(n[i]);
}
```

**In the future, please don't come here with your homework before trying to do it yourself. Thanks! :)**